# Align the labeled text in the center

Tags: circuitikz

I would like to display a characteristic of a lamp on 2 centered lines: I used the `l2` label as indicated in the manual but the 2 lines are not centered but aligned to the left.

What mistake did I make?

Thanks for your help.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage[european, straightvoltages, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
 \draw (0,0) 
  to [vsource, l=\SI{6}{V}] (0,3)
  to[lamp, l=\mbox{\SI{6}{\volt}, \SI{100}{mA}}] (3,3)
  to [lamp, l2=\SI{6}{\volt} and \SI{100}{mA}, l2 valign=c] (3,0)
  to[R, l=\SI{10}{\ohm}] (0,0)
  ;
 \end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that you mismatched vertical and horizontal alignments.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage[european, straightvoltages, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
 \draw (0,0) 
  to [vsource, l=\SI{6}{V}] (0,3)
  to[lamp, l=\mbox{\SI{6}{\volt}, \SI{100}{mA}}] (3,3)
  to [lamp, l2=\SI{6}{\volt} and \SI{100}{mA}, l2 halign=c] (3,0)
  to[R, l=\SI{10}{\ohm}] (0,0)
  ;
 \end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image: circuitikz halign]